# LVM - how to disable scrub --assume-clean

Tags: lvm, storage, software-raid

Building a raid10 array with LVM. `lvs -a -o name,raid_sync_action,sync_percent` reports `resync     60.23`. Is there a way to disable this scrub like you could do with mdraid by using the --assume-clean flag in raid creation?

Going through the arch linux they report that to stop the running data scrub safely you can run `echo idle > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action` however lvm seems todo things differently so this file location does not have what is needed, atleast on rhel8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, pass the `--nosync` option to `lvcreate`/`lvresize`. I just made the mistake of forgetting about it, so now I'm looking for a way to cancel it, that's how I got here. :D